# How to make one bring using down?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following to be displayed in, so in the first row: One Two, second row: Three Four, third row: Five.

How can I do so with will be sure to accept the answer.

```
      <div>
        <div>Four</li>
        <div>Five</li>
      </div>
```

Comment: Check the css property `columns` to display items on multiple columns.

Comment: Please don't ever vandalise your questions once you have your answer (or even before that). The point of Stack Overflow is to provide help to you *and* to those visitors that might need help with the same - or similar - problems in future. If you need to close your question for whatever reason, *before* it's been answered, you can use the close, or delete, links below the tags to your question. If you wish to dissociate yourself from the question by all means contact the team to ask for that to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One relatively simple solution is to use the flex-box approach:

```css
/* Setting up the basic 'default' display
   options: */
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  /* display: flex sets up the <ul> element
     to contain flex-items: */
  display: flex;
  /* this establishes whether the model should
     be row-based or column-based: */
  flex-direction: row;
  /* stretches the flex-items (the <li>) to
     fill the space: */
  align-items: stretch;
  /* defines whether the children may, or may
     not, wrap to a new line: */
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
li {
  display: flex-item;
  /* 0:   'flex-grow',
          the amount by which the particular
          element may grow, relative to its
          siblings.
  
     1:   'flex-shrink',
          the amount by which the element
          may shrink relative to its
          siblings.
  
     20%: 'flex-basis',
          the initial width of the particular
          element relative to its container.
  */
  flex: 0 1 20%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul {
    /* we want the elements to wrap to
       new lines at this point, so we
       change 'nowrap' to 'wrap': */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  li {
    /* here, the flex-grow is set to 2,
       meaning that an element can grow
       to twice the size of a sibling,
       flex-shrink remains the same, and
       flex-basis is now 50%, because we
       want either one or two (at most)
       elements per line: */
    flex: 2 1 50%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
  ul {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  li {
    /* while you didn't specify an alternate
       view rule for smaller screen widths, I
       added this to show how flex-boxes can
       be used to switch to a one-element per
       row alternative at tiny widths, simply
       by setting the flex-basis to 100%: */
    flex: 0 1 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/c6nkg6d4/).

Of course, the above assumes that you would like the `<li>` element alone on its own row to have the full width of that row; if that's not the case then you can simply replace the `flex: 2 1 50%` line with `flex: 0 1 50%`, which will prevent the item on a row by itself from growing in relation to its siblings.

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
li {
  display: flex-item;
  flex: 0 1 20%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  li {
    flex: 0 1 50%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
  ul {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  li {
    flex: 0 1 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/c6nkg6d4/1/).

References:

- "[Using CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)" (MDN).

Comment: could we chat about this? I am close to achieving it but looks like flex-item isn't working.

Comment: In which case I'm glad to have been of help! :)

Comment: I came across one small issue. Do you mind if I chat with you for a second? I can open up another question as well or give you bounty on this answer. Thank you David

Answer (score 0):

The media query you need is shown below. Meanwhile, [here is a Fiddle for quick-testing](https://jsfiddle.net/185t4pcd/2/). Just expand and contract (resize) the window to see what you get.

```
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            ul li{
                display: inline-block;
                width:50%;
                padding:15px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                margin:0;
                float:left;
            }
        }
```

Example:

```css
ul,li{
list-style:none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 width:50%;
 padding:15px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin:0;
 float:left;
}
}
```

```html
 
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul style={{listStyleType: 'none'}}>
<li style={{display: 'inline'}}>One</li>
<li style={{display: 'inline'}}>Two</li>
<li style={{display: 'inline'}}>Three</li>
<li style={{display: 'inline'}}>Four</li>
<li style={{display: 'inline'}}>Five</li>
</ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Row with 5, not Column with 5

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
{
    ul > li:nth-child(odd)
    {
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but could you explain what it is doing?